Unable to create Python Executable with Pyinstaller and Kivymd Application
Pyinstaller reports multiple errors and fails in building Python application using Kivy and KivyMD library's.
Application runs properly from source in virtual environment and using a different library (PYQt6) I was able to build an executable but not using Kivy / KivyMD.  I suspect the problem might be KivyMD and compatibility with Pyinstaller.
Env:

Ubuntu: 22.04
Python: 3.12
Kivy: 2.3.0
KivyMD: 2.0.1.dev0

Screenshot:

Tried different Python 3.10 to see if it works..... but got the same result.
Any suggestions greatly appreciated.
Minimal Example:
Stripped out all KivyMD and went with Python3.12, Kivy 2.3.0 in a virtual environment.  Application opens with one screen and updates a Label's text as it processes it's data.
Main.py:
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager

from data_routines import DataRtns


class StatLabel(Label):
    def on_text(self, instance, value):
        self.parent.parent.parent.parent.status = value


class Interface(ScreenManager):

    status = "Data Routines"
    err_flg = False

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.clock = Clock.schedule_once(self.process_data, 5)

    def process_data(self, dt):

        if self.status == "Data Routines":
            DataRtns.validate_database(self)
        elif self.status == "Validated Database":
            DataRtns.check_tables(self)
        elif self.status == "Checked Tables":
            DataRtns.check_defaults(self)
        elif self.status == "Checked Defaults":
            self.ids.status_indicator.text = "Finished"

        if self.status != "Finished":

            self.clock.cancel()

            if self.err_flg:
                print(self.ids.status_indicator.text)
                App.get_running_app().stop()
            else:
                self.clock = Clock.schedule_once(self.process_data, 5)


class CandoitApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = "Can Do IT Application"
        self.icon = "cando.png"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    CandoitApp().run()

data_routines.py:
from sqlite3 import connect


class DataRtns:

    db = None
    cursor = None

    @staticmethod
    def validate_database(interface):

        # Create a Connection to Data, create Database if it doesn't exist

        try:
            DataRtns.db = connect("shipping.db")
            DataRtns.cursor = DataRtns.db.cursor()
        except Exception as err:
            interface.err_flg = True
            interface.ids.status_indicator.text = "Connection Failed: " + str(err)

        if not interface.err_flg:
            interface.ids.status_indicator.text = "Validated Database"

    @staticmethod
    def check_tables(interface):

        # Validate Tables, create if they don't exist

        files = ["addresses", "schedule", "addr_types", "prefixes", "suffixes", "service_types"]

        for file in files:

            if file == "addresses":

                try:

                    DataRtns.cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS addresses(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                                            "street_no INTEGER NOT NULL, street_name TEXT NOT NULL, "
                                            "street_suffix TEXT NOT NULL, street_prefix TEXT, "
                                            "unit_suite TEXT, city TEXT NOT NULL, province TEXT NOT NULL, "
                                            "postal TEXT NOT NULL, landline TEXT, cell TEXT, "
                                            "address_type TEXT NOT NULL, map TEXT, photo TEXT, "
                                            "directions TEXT, location_notes TEXT, "
                                            "cancellations INTEGER DEFAULT 0, failures INTEGER DEFAULT 0, "
                                            "completed INTEGER DEFAULT 0, status TEXT, "
                                            "status_description TEXT, time_stamp TEXT)")

                except Exception as err:
                    DataRtns.db.close()
                    interface.err_flg = True
                    interface.ids.status_indicator.text = "Problem with addresses: " + str(err)
                    break

            elif file == "schedule":

                try:

                    DataRtns.cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS schedule(rowid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                                            "addrid INTEGER NOT NULL, address TEXT NOT NULL, "
                                            "city TEXT NOT NULL, type TEXT NOT NULL, "
                                            "notes TEXT, status TEXT, time_stamp TEXT)")

                except Exception as err:
                    DataRtns.db.close()
                    interface.err_flg = True
                    interface.ids.status_indicator.text = "Problem with schedule: " + str(err)
                    break

            elif file == "addr_types":

                try:

                    DataRtns.cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS addr_types(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                                            "type TEXT NOT NULL, multi_unit INTEGER DEFAULT 0)")

                except Exception as err:
                    DataRtns.db.close()
                    interface.err_flg = True
                    interface.ids.status_indicator.text = "Problem with addr_types: " + str(err)
                    break

            elif file == "prefixes":

                try:

                    DataRtns.cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS prefixes(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                                            "street_direction TEXT NOT NULL, abbreviation TEXT NOT NULL)")

                except Exception as err:
                    DataRtns.db.close()
                    interface.err_flg = True
                    interface.ids.status_indicator.text = "Problem with prefixes: " + str(err)
                    break

            elif file == "suffixes":

                try:

                    DataRtns.cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS suffixes(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                                            "street_type TEXT NOT NULL, abbreviation TEXT NOT NULL)")

                except Exception as err:
                    DataRtns.db.close()
                    interface.err_flg = True
                    interface.ids.status_indicator.text = "Problem with suffixes: " + str(err)
                    break

            elif file == "service_types":

                try:

                    DataRtns.cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS service_types(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                                            "type TEXT NOT NULL)")

                except Exception as err:
                    DataRtns.db.close()
                    interface.err_flg = True
                    interface.ids.status_indicator.text = "Problem with service_types: " + str(err)
                    break

        if not interface.err_flg:
            interface.ids.status_indicator.text = "Checked Tables"

    @staticmethod
    def check_defaults(interface):

        # Validate Maintenance Files, should contain default values used in the application

        files = ["addr_types", "prefixes", "suffixes", "service_types"]

        for file in files:

            if interface.err_flg:
                break

            if file == "addr_types":

                # Address Type Defaults

                values = [("Apartment Building", 1),
                          ("Assisted Living Building", 1),
                          ("Basement Apartment", 0),
                          ("Business (detached)", 0),
                          ("Condominium", 1),
                          ("Flat", 0),
                          ("House (detached)", 0),
                          ("House (linked)", 0),
                          ("Loft", 0),
                          ("Maisonette", 1),
                          ("Mall", 1),
                          ("Office Building", 1),
                          ("Plaza", 1),
                          ("Retirement Home", 1),
                          ("Row House", 1),
                          ("Seniors Residence", 1),
                          ("Store Front", 0),
                          ("Townhouse", 1),
                          ("Townhouse (no unit)", 0),
                          ("Trailer Park", 0)]

                # Access addr_types

                try:
                    sql = f"SELECT * from {file}"
                    DataRtns.cursor.execute(sql)
                    result = DataRtns.cursor.fetchall()
                except Exception as err:
                    DataRtns.db.close()
                    interface.err_flg = True
                    interface.ids.status_indicator.text = "Problem accessing addr_types: " + str(err)
                    break

                # Check Records

                if len(result) > 0:

                    for value_items in values:

                        try:
                            sql = f"SELECT * from {file} where type = '{value_items[0]}'"
                            DataRtns.cursor.execute(sql)
                            chk_result = DataRtns.cursor.fetchall()
                        except Exception as err:
                            DataRtns.db.close()
                            interface.err_flg = True
                            interface.ids.status_indicator.text = f"Problem accessing {file}: " + str(err)
                            break

                        if len(chk_result) == 0:

                            desc = value_items[0]
                            munit = value_items[1]

                            try:
                                sql = f"INSERT INTO {file} (type, multi_unit) VALUES (?, ?)"
                                vals = (f"{desc}", f"{munit}")
                                DataRtns.cursor.execute(sql, vals)
                                DataRtns.db.commit()
                            except Exception as err:
                                DataRtns.db.close()
                                interface.err_flg = True
                                interface.ids.status_indicator.text = f"Problem update {file}: " + str(err)
                                break

                else:

                    # Add Records

                    for value_items in values:

                        desc = value_items[0]
                        munit = value_items[1]

                        try:
                            sql = f"INSERT INTO {file} (type, multi_unit) VALUES (?, ?)"
                            vals = (f"{desc}", f"{munit}")
                            DataRtns.cursor.execute(sql, vals)
                            DataRtns.db.commit()
                        except Exception as err:
                            DataRtns.db.close()
                            interface.err_flg = True
                            interface.ids.status_indicator.text = f"Problem updating {file}: " + str(err)
                            break

            elif file == "prefixes":

                # Street Direction Defaults

                values = [("East", "E"),
                          ("North", "N"),
                          ("Northeast", "NE"),
                          ("Northwest", "NW"),
                          ("South", "S"),
                          ("Southeast", "SE"),
                          ("Southwest", "SW"),
                          ("West", "W")]

                # Access prefixes

                try:
                    sql = f"SELECT * from {file}"
                    DataRtns.cursor.execute(sql)
                    result = DataRtns.cursor.fetchall()
                except Exception as err:
                    DataRtns.db.close()
                    interface.err_flg = True
                    interface.ids.status_indicator.text = "Problem accessing prefixes: " + str(err)
                    break

                # Check Records

                if len(result) > 0:

                    for value_items in values:

                        try:
                            sql = f"SELECT * from {file} where street_direction = '{value_items[0]}'"
                            DataRtns.cursor.execute(sql)
                            chk_result = DataRtns.cursor.fetchall()
                        except Exception as err:
                            DataRtns.db.close()
                            interface.err_flg = True
                            interface.ids.status_indicator.text = f"Problem accessing {file}: " + str(err)
                            break

                        if len(chk_result) == 0:

                            direction = value_items[0]
                            short_desc = value_items[1]

                            try:
                                sql = f"INSERT INTO {file} (street_direction, abbreviation) VALUES (?, ?)"
                                vals = (f"{direction}", f"{short_desc}")
                                DataRtns.cursor.execute(sql, vals)
                                DataRtns.db.commit()
                            except Exception as err:
                                DataRtns.db.close()
                                interface.err_flg = True
                                interface.ids.status_indicator.text = f"Problem updating {file}: " + str(err)
                                break

                else:

                    # Add Records

                    for value_items in values:

                        direction = value_items[0]
                        short_desc = value_items[1]

                        try:
                            sql = f"INSERT INTO {file} (street_direction, abbreviation) VALUES (?, ?)"
                            vals = (f"{direction}", f"{short_desc}")
                            DataRtns.cursor.execute(sql, vals)
                            DataRtns.db.commit()
                        except Exception as err:
                            DataRtns.db.close()
                            interface.err_flg = True
                            interface.ids.status_indicator.text = f"Problem updating {file}: " + str(err)
                            break

            elif file == "suffixes":

                # Street Type Defaults

                values = [("Abbey", "Abbey"),
                          ("Acres", "Acres"),
                          ("Alley", "Alley"),
                          ("Avenue", "Ave"),
                          ("Bay", "Bay"),
                          ("Beach", "Beach"),
                          ("Boulevard", "Blvd"),
                          ("Bye-pass", "Bypass"),
                          ("Campus", "Campus"),
                          ("Centre", "Ctr"),
                          ("Circle", "Cir"),
                          ("Concession", "Conc"),
                          ("Corners", "Crnrs"),
                          ("Court", "Crt"),
                          ("Cove", "Cove"),
                          ("Crescent", "Cres"),
                          ("Crossing", "Cross"),
                          ("Downs", "Downs"),
                          ("Drive", "Dr"),
                          ("Esplanade", "Espl"),
                          ("Expressway", "Expy"),
                          ("Extension", "Exten"),
                          ("Freeway", "Fwy"),
                          ("Glen", "Glen"),
                          ("Grove", "Grove"),
                          ("Harbour", "Harbr"),
                          ("Heights", "Hts"),
                          ("Highway", "Hwy"),
                          ("Hill", "Hill"),
                          ("Key", "Key"),
                          ("Landing", "Landing"),
                          ("Lane", "Lane"),
                          ("Line", "Line"),
                          ("Mall", "Mall"),
                          ("Manor", "Manor"),
                          ("Meadows", "Meadows"),
                          ("Mews", "Mews"),
                          ("Mountain", "Mtn"),
                          ("Orchard", "Orch"),
                          ("Park", "Pk"),
                          ("Parkway", "Pky"),
                          ("Place", "Pl"),
                          ("Plaza", "Plaza"),
                          ("Promenade", "Prom"),
                          ("Ridge", "Ridge"),
                          ("Road", "Rd"),
                          ("Route", "Rte"),
                          ("Square", "Sq"),
                          ("Street", "St"),
                          ("Terrace", "Terr"),
                          ("Towers", "Towers"),
                          ("Townline", "Tline"),
                          ("Trail", "Trail"),
                          ("View", "View"),
                          ("Village", "Vilge"),
                          ("Way", "Way")]

                # Access Street Types

                try:
                    sql = f"SELECT * from {file}"
                    DataRtns.cursor.execute(sql)
                    result = DataRtns.cursor.fetchall()
                except Exception as err:
                    DataRtns.db.close()
                    interface.err_flg = True
                    interface.ids.status_indicator.text = f"Problem accessing suffixes: " + str(err)
                    break

                # Check Records

                if len(result) > 0:

                    for value_items in values:

                        try:
                            sql = f"SELECT * from {file} where street_type = '{value_items[0]}'"
                            DataRtns.cursor.execute(sql)
                            chk_result = DataRtns.cursor.fetchall()
                        except Exception as err:
                            DataRtns.db.close()
                            interface.err_flg = True
                            interface.ids.status_indicator.text = f"Problem accessing {file}: " + str(err)
                            break

                        if len(chk_result) == 0:

                            strt_type = value_items[0]
                            short_desc = value_items[1]

                            try:
                                sql = f"INSERT INTO {file} (street_type, abbreviation) VALUES (?, ?)"
                                vals = (f"{strt_type}", f"{short_desc}")
                                DataRtns.cursor.execute(sql, vals)
                                DataRtns.db.commit()
                            except Exception as err:
                                DataRtns.db.close()
                                interface.err_flg = True
                                interface.ids.status_indicator = f"Problem updateing {file}: " + str(err)
                                break

                else:

                    # Add Records

                    for value_items in values:

                        strt_type = value_items[0]
                        short_desc = value_items[1]

                        try:
                            sql = f"INSERT INTO {file} (street_type, abbreviation) VALUES (?, ?)"
                            vals = (f"{strt_type}", f"{short_desc}")
                            DataRtns.cursor.execute(sql, vals)
                            DataRtns.db.commit()
                        except Exception as err:
                            DataRtns.db.close()
                            interface.err_flg = True
                            interface.ids.status_indicator.text = f"Problem updating {file}: " + str(err)
                            break

            elif file == "service_types":

                # Service Type Defaults

                values = ["Delivery",
                          "Desk Work",
                          "Dog Walking",
                          "Gardening",
                          "Lawn Mow",
                          "Leaf Raking",
                          "Other",
                          "Pet Sitting",
                          "Put Garbage Out",
                          "Snow Shoveling",
                          "Trash Removal"]

                # Access service_types

                try:
                    sql = f"SELECT * from {file}"
                    DataRtns.cursor.execute(sql)
                    result = DataRtns.cursor.fetchall()
                except Exception as err:
                    DataRtns.db.close()
                    interface.err_flg = True
                    interface.ids.status_indicator.text = f"Problem accessing service_types: " + str(err)
                    break

                # Check Records

                if len(result) > 0:

                    for value_item in values:

                        try:
                            sql = f"SELECT * from {file} where type = '{value_item}'"
                            DataRtns.cursor.execute(sql)
                            chk_result = DataRtns.cursor.fetchall()
                        except Exception as err:
                            DataRtns.db.close()
                            interface.err_flg = True
                            interface.ids.status_indicator.text = f"Problem accessing {file}: " + str(err)
                            break

                        if len(chk_result) == 0:

                            try:
                                sql = f"INSERT INTO {file} (type) VALUES ('{value_item}')"
                                DataRtns.cursor.execute(sql)
                                DataRtns.db.commit()
                            except Exception as err:
                                DataRtns.db.close()
                                interface.err_flg = True
                                interface.ids.status_indicator.text = f"Problem updating {file}: " + str(err)
                                break

                else:

                    # Add Records

                    for value_item in values:

                        try:
                            sql = f"INSERT INTO {file} (type) VALUES ('{value_item}')"
                            DataRtns.cursor.execute(sql)
                            DataRtns.db.commit()
                        except Exception as err:
                            DataRtns.db.close()
                            interface.err_flg = True
                            interface.ids.status_indicator.text = f"Problem updating {file}: " + str(err)
                            break

        if not interface.err_flg:

            DataRtns.cursor.close()
            DataRtns.db.close()

            interface.ids.status_indicator.text = "Checked Defaults"

candoit.kv:
Interface:
    Screen:
        name: "Splash_Screen"
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: .6, .8, 1, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        AnchorLayout:
            anchor_x: "center"
            anchor_y: "center"
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "vertical"
                size_hint: None, None
                width: dp(300)
                height: dp(300)
                Image:
                    source: "cando.png"
                    size_hint: 1, 0.9
                StatLabel:
                    id: status_indicator
                    text: root.status
                    font_size: "32sp"
                    color: [0, 0, 0, 1]
                    size_hint: 1, 0.1

Results in the above.... very frustrating !

Please post a [mcve].
